# Password for Azure AD User

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Graph API to read user information from Azure AD. I am getting all the user information in the response except the password. Is there anyway I can get that? 
I am calling this API. ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetAUser))

> https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version

Comment: Why would you expect to get the user's password? Being able to retrieve the user's password would be woefully insecure.

Comment: I am providing SAML based authentication as well, if at all I need to get the password is it possible by granting some more permissions?

Comment: No, because AD *doesn't store the password*. Passwords are stored as a one-way salted hash. You can check that the user has entered the correct password by applying the same hash, but you can never retrieve the original password.

Comment: You mention SAML-based authentication. What's the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? Ask *that* question.

Comment: I am importing users from azure AD using graph API, I am adding the user information in my application's database. I want them to be able to login to my application through my login portal by providing their azure ad credentials

Comment: All I need is to verify if they are entering the correct password, u said I can do that by applying some hash. How will I get that?

Comment: You should use AD authentication directly in your application, via federation. They authenticate against AD, which provides a token that they can use to authenticate with your application.

Comment: Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb897402.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [Graph API References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity):

> The passwordProfile property always returns null. This is to prevent the user’s password from being displayed. You can reset the user’s password by updating the passwordProfile property.

If you are looking to have someone authenticate to your service using their AAD Account, you should either use Federation to have your authentication provider trust the AAD authentication provider, or you can even register your application in our system, and use AAD as your authentication provider.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am using SAML based authentication now.